# ExecutorService slower than sequential file process of copying file

Tags: java, synchronized, executorservice

This is my code for copying file from one directory to other using `ExecutorService` but it turned out to be slower than sequential operation. Am using apache FileUtils copyFile method which is not synchronized. What's the problem?

```
public class ExecutorService {

private static java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService pool;


public ExecutorService() {

    pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
}


public static void main(String arg[]) {

    long a = System.currentTimeMillis();

    new ExecutorService();

    List<File> listFiles = null;
    try {
        listFiles = FileUtility.getFileNamesToExtract(new File(
                "C:/Users/User/Desktop/XSLT Source/Input XML"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.size(); i++)
        pool.submit(new FileTransfer(listFiles.get(i), i));

    pool.shutdown();

    try {
        pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long b = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((b - a) / 1000);

  }

 }
```

---

```
 public class FileTransfer implements Runnable{

private File file = null;
private int num = 0;

public FileTransfer(File file, int i) {
     this.file = file;
     this.num = i;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Processing="+file.getName());
        FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File("C:/Users/gursahibsahni/Desktop/thread pool files/"+num+"_"+file.getName()+num));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

> What's the problem?

I can't really see why you would think a thread pool can speed up file transfer. Try this: run your single-threaded version and monitor CPU usage. My expectation: it will be below 10%.

File copying is not a CPU-intensive operation and moreover, parallelizing it only means you create a difficult disk access pattern, which slows down the whole thing and probably also causes more file fragmentation.